# Collectd running but not collecting anything?

Tags: collectd

This is only my third installation of collectd.

Previous two went without a hitch. However, on this server (Centos 5.3) it starts and collects absolutely nothing. Directory where it should be collecting ( /opt/collectd/var/lib/collectd ) to remains empty.

It compiled without any problems, and there are no problems reported when I start it with -t or -T.

Where to start looking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As expected, it was my mistake. I recompiled it with --enable-debug and saw that network plugin was enabled and multicasting my collected results.